# RSpec doesn't show full difference between return and expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When a run a test with JSON, the rspec doesn't show the full spec, so I can't see the diference between return and expected.

The message of diff is shortened with **...**

```
expected: "{\"id\":1,\"number\":1,\"sequential\":1,\"emitted_at\":\"2014-01-01T13:35:21.000Z\",\"status\":\"aut...erenceds_attributes\":[{\"id\":null,\"nfe_key\":\"42150707697707000148550010000020101000020105\"}]}"
     got: "{\"id\":1,\"number\":1,\"sequential\":1,\"emitted_at\":\"2014-01-01T13:35:21.000Z\",\"status\":\"aut...erenceds_attributes\":[{\"id\":null,\"nfe_key\":\"42150707697707000148550010000020101000020105\"}]}"
```

**aut...erenceds_attributes** look in middle of message

My script test:

```
RSpec.describe InvoiceSerializer do
  let(:invoice) do
    build :invoice, :testing_serializer
  end

  subject { described_class.new invoice }

  it "returns a json" do
    expected = {
      id: 1,
      number: 1,
      sequential: 1,
      emitted_at: "2014-01-01T13:35:21.000Z",
      status: "authorized",
      invoice_bills_attributes: [{
        id: nil,
        expire_at: "2014-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        value: "1.23"
      }],
      ...
    }.to_json

    expect(subject.to_json).to eq expected
  end
end
```

[Example of error in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HR0w.png)

What gem/plugin or expectation that you use to check your test?

I use the console and Rubymine IDE.

Now I use:

```
puts "1 --> #{subject.to_json}"
puts "2 --> #{expected}"
```

And I don't like to write this for to debbug my test.

Comment: version of rspec?  is it rspec-rails?

Comment: One idea: test that the `.to_json` method is returning a String, then test that it can be parsed via `JSON.parse`. That tells you your method is returning valid JSON. Then, with the parsed data hash, compare _that_ to your expected Hash. The output still may not be perfect (can't recall just now how that outputs), but then you could just loop over the hashes and compare each key/value pair instead. That will zero you in on what exactly is different between them.

Comment: I use rspec-rails - 3.5.2

Comment: Rspec doesn't have a configuration to output result test?

Comment: @Linielson Have you found an answer for this ?

Comment: @Oxynum I have not found the best way to resolve this. We still use the tests in the same way as in the example. :/

Answer (score 9):

Set `RSpec::Support::ObjectFormatter.default_instance.max_formatted_output_length` to a high value

Update: as Yurri suggested, it might be better to better to set it to `nil`

Comment: Or setting it to `nil` will prevent `RSpec` from truncating the formatted output at all

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/main/lib/rspec/expectations/configuration.rb#L70 here is the source.

Answer (score 4):

To build on previous answers, and utilize the `RSpec.configure` syntax you'll want to use something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.expect_with :rspec do |c|
     # Or a very large value, if you do want to truncate at some point
    c.max_formatted_output_length = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help: https://github.com/waterlink/rspec-json_expectations

As a bonus, it allows you to specify your tests in terms of a subset of attributes, which can be used to create more granular tests.

Comment: I liked this, but I need to use "equals" and not "include".